# How to manage memory in recursive function that creates new lists with each recursive function call?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm writing a function to count the possible paths of length `M` in an `N-dimensions` grid starting from points specified in list `X_n` where the dimensions of the grid are given in list `D_n`.

I am passing the current coordinates and dimensions of the grid to the `Solve` function with `lists`. However, this means I am making many list copies, as can be seen below.

```
def Solve(X_n, D_n, M):
"""Find number of paths of length M in grid of dimensions D_n we can get starting at X_n"""

    #using dynamic methods to avoid unnecessary calculations by storing number of paths
    # from a given grid member that are available. This will be 2^N except for edge cases
    if M == 1:
        return solve_grid[tuple(X_n)] if solve_grid[tuple(X_n)] else count_em(X_n, D_n)

    #identify which current coordinates are at an edge and don't modify these in wrong direction
    diff = np.subtract(D_n, X_n)
    good_add = [i for i, d in enumerate(diff) if  d!= 0]
    good_subtract = [i for i, x in enumerate(X_n) if x != 0]

    return_val = 0

    #here's my concern: what's going to happen with all these lists?
    #is there a better way to handle this?
    for idx in good_add:
        new_x = list(X_n)
        new_x[idx] += 1
        return_val += Solve(new_x, D_n, M-1)

    for idx in good_subtract:
        new_x = list(X_n)
        new_x[idx] -= 1
        return_val += Solve(new_x, D_n, M-1)

    return return_val
```

My understanding is that Python has a write-only type memory management system, so when I am creating many duplicate lists (as this function certainly will), these duplicate objects will all point to the same item so long as they are not modified. This seems like the above should be not so bad...

1. **Is this ok memory-wise or will it blow up?**
2. If it will blow up, what's a smart way to do this with lists (they're so convenient)?
3. If not, is using an `f(*args)` style function the best way to recursively pass coordinates and dimensions?

Comment: @rth It does work for my purposes, but I am more interested in learning the theory/best uses for when my system is more limited.

Comment: Well, yes, but your question is very broad. Any recursive function in python will make copies of objects (including lists in this case) and there is not much you can do about it, apart from optimizing the function. For instance,  if `X_n` are large enough, you could use numpy arrays everywhere and avoid lists altogether.   If you run this on a limited system and memory is an issue, I would just implement this function in a lower level language (e.g. C) or more conveniently Cython, in order to better control memory allocation and reduce python overhead.

Comment: @rth interesting, how would numpy arrays make this more effiicient? That's probably advice I'm looking for, but I'm wondering why they're better.

Comment: X_n can be anything from 0 to max of correponding D_n. D_n can be anything from 1 to 1000, and M can be anything from 1 to max (D_n). I've only tested my code on small use cases...and N can be anything from 1 to 10.

Comment: Ok, this is confusing. Could you please edit your question and add a simple and self-contained example of how you typically use the `Solve` function?

Comment: @rth Sorry, but I don't want to do that because, like I said, I'm trying to ask a more general question. Use cases could vary, best practice for minimizing memory use with recursive functions that generate lists probably don't vary, or if they do, seems like that should be part of the answer.